# Can Android Studio remove multiple elements from an array? How?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm practice developing an app but I met a problem. I want remove two elements from an array but android studio only can remove one and if I adding one more the app will crash, below is my code and now I only put one code to remove the first element and i need to remove last element otherwise the choice for answer will mix the array.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

String quizData[][] = {
        {"quadrilateral","quadrilateral","triangle","heptagon","pentagon","hexagon","decagon","Which one is the green polygon just now ?"},
        {"triangle","triangle","heptagon","quadrilateral","pentagon","octagon","decagon","Which one is the red polygon just now ?"},
        {"circle","circle","triangle","quadrilateral","pentagon","nonagon","decagon","Which one is the black polygon just now ?"},
        {"star","star","circle","octagon","pentagon","hexagon","decagon","Which one is the brown polygon just now ?"},
        {"decagon","decagon","triangle","circle","pentagon","hexagon","star","Which one is the pink polygon just now ?"},
        {"heptagon","heptagon","decagon","quadrilateral","pentagon","hexagon","star","Which one is the yellow polygon just now ?"},
        {"hexagon","hexagon","decagon","heptagon","pentagon","octagon","star","Which one is the sky blue polygon just now ?"},
        {"nonagon","nonagon","circle","quadrilateral","triangle","hexagon","star","Which one is the orange polygon just now ?"},
        {"pentagon","pentagon","nonagon","octagon","heptagon","hexagon","circle","Which one is the purple polygon just now ?"},
        {"octagon","octagon","triangle","quadrilateral","pentagon","hexagon","star","Which one is the dark blue polygon just now ?"}
};

public void Show_Next_Quiz(){

        Random random = new Random();
        int Random_Num = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

        ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(Random_Num);

        Question1.setText(quiz.get(7));

    iV1.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV2.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV3.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV4.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV5.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV6.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );

        Right_Answer = quiz.get(1);
        quiz.remove(0);
        //quiz.remove(7);

        Collections.shuffle(quiz);

        ans1.setText(quiz.get(1));
        ans2.setText(quiz.get(2));
        ans3.setText(quiz.get(3));
        ans4.setText(quiz.get(4));
        ans5.setText(quiz.get(5));
        ans6.setText(quiz.get(6));

        quizArray.remove(Random_Num);

}
```

Comment: Android Studio cant code. So no :P
Look at the documentation of `remove()` for `ArrayList` in Java. You will know what to do from there.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)

Comment: Owhhh i will use some time to figure out and thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is crash because you're trying to remove an item from the List by using an incorrect item position.

For example, assume that you have an ArrayList with size of 7:

```
ArrayList<String> quizzes = new ArrayList<>(7);
```

the quiz items from quizzes will be in `0 - 6` range of index position. When you're removing the first item with:

```
quizzes.remove(0);
```

the quizzes size is now 6. Now you can only access the items from `0 to 5` index position. It will gives error when you're trying to remove an item with item position beyond that. So, the following code won't work and gives you a crash:

```
quizzes.remove(7);
```

because you're trying to access a non-exist item position.

So, you can't depends on the item position to remove the item in your case. You can use [public boolean remove(Object o)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList#remove(java.lang.Object)) instead.

```
quizzes.remove("triangle");
```

Probably what you need is an another ArrayList for `ansX` views to match the size of the questions. Something like this:

```
int sizeOfTheQuiz = 6;
ArrayList<String> quizzes = new ArrayList<>(sizeOfTheQuiz);

ArrayList<TextView> tvAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
tvAnswers.add(ans1);
tvAnswers.add(ans2);
tvAnswers.add(ans3);
tvAnswers.add(ans4);
tvAnswers.add(ans5);
tvAnswers.add(ans6);

// size of the quizzes must not larger than tvAnswers
for(int i = 0; i < quizzes.size(); i++) {
  tvAnswers.get(i).setText(quizzes.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Owhh Thanks!! You help me a lot!!

Comment: Great! Please take a look at the current answer for more details.